# Data in child / detail form not displaying

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following view with an inlineformset for two models:

1. Orders, the master / parent model
2. LineitemInfo, the detail / child model.

FormSet

```
LineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Orders, LineitemInfo,
can_delete=True,
exclude = ('ordernotes',))
```

The edit order_edit view works fine for the master / parent form, but does not display the child records. I can add records to the child form and they will save, they do not display however when I select that record (I checked the database separately).

```
def order_edit(request, pk):
order = get_object_or_404(Orders, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(request.POST, instance=order)
        if lineitem_formset.is_valid():
            order.save()
            lineitem_formset.save()

        return redirect('order_list')
else:
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(instance=Orders())
return render(request, "orders/order_edit.html", {"form": form, "lineitem_formset": lineitem_formset, })
```

I just get the empty fields on the child / detail form where the data should display. What am I missing? TIA

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate to answer my own questions, I was calling instance of an empty Order() model rather than the instance of the populated model. So:

```
lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(instance=Orders())
```

should have been:

```
lineitem_formset = LineFormSet(instance=order)
```